# How to handle user input that is too long?

Tags: input, validation, user-experience

It is common to check if entered password is at least # characters long, or if user input is not left empty. However, I see a few websites testing if user input is not unusually long.

Typical (MySQL) database design will dedicate 100-255 characters for e.g. to first name, last name input. Longer input will cause loss of data. What is the recommended way of handling abnormal input as such?

Answer (score 0):

Your inputText component should have a maxLength attribute or something like that.

This will block the user input when he reaches the maximum input lenght.

If this is not applicable for you, could you clarify the context and technology used ?

Comment: What about user intentionally removing the `maxlength` attribute and submitting the form? I have done that quite a few times on purpose when website has had unreasonable input length limits. Should this be treated as program Exception?

Comment: You could check the inputLenght in the webpage (with the maxLenght). And also on the server side (in Java) and return an error message if the input is too long.

Comment: You could also read more on validating forms in web pages here :http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Answer (score 0):

From a UX standpoint you could simply have an infield placeholder that tells the user the length of the requirement. Most of the time an average user wont exceed this. From a technical standpoint use some JS to count the characters entered. Once the user reaches that specific amount place a small alert that might resemble a tooltip just over the entry field. This would indicate to the user that they have exceeded the maximum amount of characters and allow them to fix the issue.